# How to ignore one key and validate all key for having non empty value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

So I'm Learning javascripts array functions and found one solution too but it is using Object.fromEntries
but in my angular project I have old es version and cant update it due to some reason.

so the problem is I have one array of object which is

```
var a =
    [{
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    },
    {
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 45454,
        "code": "2121212",
        "amount": "",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    }]
```

and I want to check all object should have value in all keys except key "id"

so I was using below code to achieve it

```
a.map((ele: any) => Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(ele)
          .filter(([key, val]) => key != "id" && val)
      ));
```

still I dont get the desired result as

```
    [{
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    }]
```

below is the desired output

```
[{
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    }]
    only one object bcz all key contains value expect id key
```

which is wrong.
So any javascript function which can help?

Comment: What is the expected result? An array containing all "valid" objects? Or something else?

Comment: @SalmanA result is expected of array containing object which satisfy condition or empty array if condition is not matched in my case it should give ```[{
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    }] ```
but if amount key is empty then i should get empty array

Comment: Define "empty" though. null, 0, false?

Comment: @SalmanA empty value of key means null or undefined or ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
var a =
    [{
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    }, {
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": null,
        "id":""
    },
{
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": 0,
        "id":""
    }];
var result = a.filter(function(item){
   return Object.entries(item).every(function([key, val]){
        return key === "id" || (val != null && val !== "");
    })
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is not correct bcz if any other field other than id is empty it still sends the same array object

Comment: @SanjaySahani please check again, I have fixed the code.

Comment: wow ! your solution works but can u please explain why are we using ===? bcz here I want to ignore checking id key and also use of Boolean? bcz values are either string or number

Comment: I have noticed one thing your piece of code ignore the object if its attribute has value as 0. In my case 0 is also i valid value

Comment: @SanjaySahani I have edited for empty string null and undefined. 0 will be accepted as well here.

Comment: I think ur solution is not working bcz if you add one more object in array with any value as zero it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @SanjaySahani The edited answer works as expected. I have added one more object which contains isTaxDetails value 0

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you are doing it right with the first way (i.e. Object.fromEntries + Object.entries + Array.filter)

There is another way which is to use Object.entries + Array.reduce to reduce your entries array into an Object.

However, in my experience, the first solution you implemented always yielded better execution time in my case so I would stick with that.

---

**Edit:** From looking at your desired output and what your current input is, here is what you want to use.

```
var a = [
    {
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 44444,
        "code": "5555555",
        "amount": "5,555",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    },
    {
        "dateOfDeposit": "2022-06-08T18:30:00.000Z",
        "cNumber": 45454,
        "code": "2121212",
        "amount": "",
        "isTaxDetails": true,
        "id":""
    },
];

var filteredArray = a.filter((item) => Object.entries(item).every(([key, value]) => key === "id" || typeof value != "string" || value.length > 0));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: can u pls show to do it?

Comment: Once I have a PC at reach, I will, but please edit your question to clarify what you want, going through your post and comments, it’s a bit confusing to understand what you expect as a result. Do you want to filter the attributes inside your objects or filter object in your array?

Comment: I want to filter attributes inside object